# setSpan() will only produce one image

Tags: android, textview, android-image, spannablestring

```
            SpannableStringBuilder authorText = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
            ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_birdhead);
            for (Author a : mStory.authors) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(a.authorName)) {

                String prefix = "";
                if (count == 0) {
                    prefix = "By: ";
                } else if (count > 0 && count < mStory.authors.size()-1) {
                    prefix = ", ";
                } else {
                    prefix = " and ";
                }

                authorText.append(prefix + a.authorName + " ");
                authorText.setSpan(is, authorText.length()-1, authorText.length(), 0);
                //authorText.setSpan(is, authorText.length()-2, authorText.length()-1, 0);
                              //^ I put a second one there just to check is two will populate
                count++;
            }
```

So.. It goes through a for loop anyway, but I put 2 setSpan()'s to see if the last iteration would populate 2 images. It only populates an image at the very end of the string. Maybe there is a certain flag i have to put in for setspan to produce multiple?

Comment: You probably need to create a new ImageSpan for each iteration. You can't use the same span multiple times - it will just reposition the span.

Comment: Just figured that out... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder authorText = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
            ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_birdhead);
            for (Author a : mStory.authors) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(a.authorName)) {

                String prefix = "";
                if (count == 0) {
                    prefix = "By: ";
                } else if (count > 0 && count < mStory.authors.size()-1) {
                    prefix = ", ";
                } else {
                    prefix = " and ";
                }

                authorText.append(prefix + a.authorName + " ");
                authorText.setSpan(is, authorText.length()-1, authorText.length(), 0);

                is = new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_birdhead);

                authorText.setSpan(is, authorText.length()-2, authorText.length()-1, 0);
                              //^ I put a second one there just to check is two will populate
                count++;
            }
```